# How to incrementally merge large branches with Git?

Tags: git, merge

**Overview:**

We have a fairly large (~10M LOC) repository that we want to handle with Git. We need to do complicated merges between development branches that are too big to do in one shot. However, it appears Git does not support this. After you commit a "merge" between two branches, Git assumes *all* the files on those branches have been addressed. What is the best workflow to incrementally work on a huge merge?

**Background:**

We want to distribute the work over several commits and several developers. The code base is being actively updated by different teams via independent CVS repos. So the work on their branches are just tarball code drops with no commit history between drops.

Our plan was to store the drops on different branches like this:

Master : Rel 1 -> Rel 2

Site B :   \ -> Rel 1.1

Our team is intended to do work similar to Site B, but Site B may continue to work in parallel. So we will keep the "Master" and "Site B" branches untouched for future imports. We will create a new development branch for our work. The first step being merging the difference between "Rel 1" and "Rel 2" onto the Rel 1.1 work. Essentially a 3-way merge between the "Master" and "Site B" branches.

Doing individual merge-file operations seems clunky and doesn't preserve any actual history. Similar with doing cherry-picks.

Any advice?

Comment: Use Git how it's supposed to be used: proper repositories with proper history. Then merging should not cause that much trouble (and you can even keep working while the merge is done).

Comment: @knittl: This isn't the standard use-case for Git merging, I understand. But unfortunately we've got multiple development teams that don't work in the same repository. We're hoping for something more akin to a Perforce Integration, where you can integrate between branches with subsets of files in different changelists. Finishing one integration doesn't close the door on P4 correctly calculating integrations/merges on the remaining files. Git doesn't seem to allow this as an option.

Comment: Yes, because Git always works on the complete tree. Note that you do not need to merge files which have not changed between the branches, or have only changed in a single branch. Have you actually tried your approach? Considering correct ancestry information between commits the merge should not be too bad. But in the end, how do your developers get the merged code when they are not working with this Git repository?

Comment: @knittl: The local developers will use this Git repository going forward. We're merging code from a base product line into a stream for our more specific product line. And we don't push our code deltas back to the base line. It's a bit troublesome, but that's the fun of working at a large company.

Comment: @agentchuck, Git supports ["subtree merging"](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) which allows you to update only a part of the project's tree (represented by a directory) with the history of another *complete* project. Dunno how this compares to that Perforce Integration you've mentioned but maybe this could help your case.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but since it just came up for me from a related google search and doesn't have an answer, I'm answering it now.

The [git imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) tool handles the problem by supporting incremental, collaborative merges.  The imerge docs point to a great [blog post](https://softwareswirl.blogspot.com/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html) about how to use it.